# The headphone works only when different levels for L/R are set

Tags: sound, headphones

My headphones suddenly became strange- the voice was pure.
I solved the problem, setting the L/R levels 40/60. That's to say, the voice is OK only on different L/R levels.

I can configure it on my Laptop, however I faced the same problem when using on my phone.

What's wrong with the headphone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about hardware/electronics diagnostics & nothing whatsoever to do with sound design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ground connection (shield) ripped off, likely in the connector or close to it, with the grounds of the phones still being connected to each other but no longer to the amplifier's ground.  So both headphones are now connected in series, delivering the difference between left and right signals, though with different polarity.

Volume most likely is heavily reduced as well.
[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: I'm not seeing how the physics of that adds up. Disconnecting the ground would simply leave two open circuits.